# Multiple choice R and Shiny

Tags: r, postgresql, checkbox, shiny

I'm new in R + shiny and have to code simple app with multiple choice and put results in SQL query. But, it returns error which i don't know how to solve. The problem looks like i m not able to put multiple choice in SQL query.

So, when i put results from checkbox in SQL query (I'm using predicate "IN" with list from checkbox) i get this error:

```
values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2            #i chose 2 options
```

Also, if you choose only one option in checkbox everything works correct.

My Shiny and R code is:

```
tabPanel("Scientists",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = "Departmentrs",
                                  choices = list(801, 802, 804, 805, 806), 
                                  selected = 801)
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
             )
           )
  )
```

And Server code is:

```
 output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    sql_2 <- "SELECT * from scientists
            WHERE department_number IN (?numb)  #<- i put results from checkbox there
            AND degree IN (?deg);"
            . . . . . . 
    if (is.null(input$checkGroup) | is.null(input$checkGroup_sot))          
      query <- sqlInterpolate(ANSI(), "SELECT * from scientists;")
    
    else {query <- sqlInterpolate(ANSI(), sql_2, 
                                  numb = input$checkGroup,
                                  deg = input$checkGroup_sot)
    }
    outp <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
    ret <- DT::datatable(outp)
    return(ret)
  })
```

What should i do? I tried to find something, but nothing helped.

Comment: You didn't define `query` in `dbGetQuery(con, query)`. Do you mean `sql_2`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, Yes, it's because i also have some code between ```sql_2  
```
and 
```dbGetQuery
```
I' ll add it to question

Comment: See <https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues/193>.